# What Tattva is Ganesha

Tags: puranas, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, ganesha, gaudiya-vaishnavism

So, I come from an Iyer background, but during my scriptural study and even before I felt inclined towards Vishnu worship. While I do worship Bhagavan Maha Vishnu as the supreme being. I still wish to continue certain Shaiva aspects like always invoking Ganesha first and even Murugan prayer. I want to know which Tattva Ganesha and Murugan would be considered. As well as their relation to Shiva and Vishnu and his Tattvas and their possible difference to Jiva Tattva. Please provide a glossary with all terms and scriptural references.

Comment: Cool, efficient and likable administration.

Comment: Elaborate please sir

Comment: He is naturally  lovable and respected by all, first to be worshipped for any important activity. Cleverness e.g., in single  bhhoo_pradikshina short cut  around parents defeating Kumaraswamy in race competition. Administration of all ganas, killing Asura with his elephant tusk.

Comment: If You Go by sri Vaishnava perspective then Ganesha is a Jiva. If you go outside that, then Brahma vaivarta purana mentions that Krishna himself was born as Ganesha which makes him parabrahma tattva